# What's the history and content of Coffee Cantata from Johann Sebastian Bach?

Tags: coffee-culture, history

A few days ago, I have seen the title **Coffee Cantata** from *Johann Sebastian Bach* will be staged soon in the opera house. I wonder, what is this cantata about?

Answer (score 1):

Coffee Cantata is also known as "Schweigt stille, plaudert nicht (Be still, stop chattering) or BWV 211.

It is composed around 1732-1735 by Bach in Leipzig.

It is known as a cantata, but actually it has a story and looks like a mini opera. In the opera, the father tries to stop her daughter from drinking coffee. However, the daughter loves coffee and sings nice lyrical praises to coffee. A well-known sentence is this: *"If I couldn't, three times a day, be allowed to drink my little cup of coffee, in my anguish I will turn into a shriveled-up roast goat".*

[More info on history of the cantata can be found on its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweigt_stille,_plaudert_nicht,_BWV_211).

[You may listen the Coffee Cantata from Youtube](https://youtu.be/H5Ocydot-vA).